# PHP variable appears to be null while it is not

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a small php class which i have edited a little to ask my question.
The class is a shown beloww

```
class Register
{

    public $notification = null;

    public function __construct()
   {
       create_connection();
      $this->validate_register();
    }
    public function validate_register()
    {
            //edit: missing double quote close
        $select_register = "SELECT * FROM `student_reg`";

        if($select_register_run = mysql_query($select_register))
        {
            $rows_returned = mysql_num_rows($select_register_run);
            if($rows_returned >= 1)
            {
                $this->notification = 'error';
            }else if($rows_returned == 0){
                $this->notification = 'success';
            }
        }else{
            $this->notification = 'error';
        }

        if($this->notification != null)
        {
            echo 'not null';

        }else{ echo 'null';}
    }
}
$new_register = new Register();
?>
```

It is clear that from the class, at any possible level, there is a value assigned to `$this->notification`. But for some reason, the class 'echoes' null.

The `creat_connection()` i built functions works perfectly but i have ommited it for the purpose of this question.

Why is this the case?

Comment: Missing quote " at the end of this line ? $select_register = "SELECT * FROM `student_reg`;

Comment: Seems like the script can't get past this line: `if($select_register_run = mysql_query($select_register))` Do you have error_reporting(E_ALL); on?

Comment: That was an error while retyping the code here.. the mysql is okay

Comment: What's the value on $rows_returned? Maybe it's returning a non-numerical value?

Comment: You don't keep the mysql connection anywhere in the class context. Missing something like `$this->databaseConnection = create_connection();` You really should use PDO or Mysqli

Comment: var_dump($this->notification);
before
if($this->notification != null)

Comment: Just a side note: You shouldn't use `mysql_query` because it's deprecated and will be removed in the future. Use `mysqli_query` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if $rows_returned is less than 1 and not equal to 0, the code will echo 'null', so I suggest you echo $rows_returned.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this...

```
$select_register_run = mysql_query($select_register);
if($select_register_run){
//rest code
```

instead of

```
if($select_register_run = mysql_query($select_register))
```